# Putting a rain barrel on a deck or on a stand

Tags: water

I'd like to have a rain barrel setup directly connected to soaker hoses (that will eventually be electronically controlled) to water a garden on-demand. The rain barrel obviously has to be above the garden beds (what's the minimum height differential here?), so my placement options are:

- On the deck next to the garden beds. The deck is well built, but the place that the barrel would go is on the deck, lofted above the septic tank. This will put an additional ~200 pounds static load onto the roof of the septic tank. Will this cause an issue?
- On a stand on the lawn. I assume I'd have to lay down a gravel/stone dust packed base, some large pavers, and then build a relatively beefy wooden stand to hold the rain barrel up.

Which of these options (or potentially others) would be best?

Edit: I'm mostly looking for longevity and safety. I am happy with both locations from an aesthetic perspective. The deck is easier because I don't have to dig/fill, but the footings being on top of the septic are a structural concern that I'm asking to have verified

Comment: Minimum height has to exceed the losses in the piping system otherwise it won’t flow or you add a pump.

Comment: @SolarMike agreed - are there rough numbers there? I have a (two, actually) windshield fluid pump, would that provide sufficient pressure/flow (the ford ones are pretty powerful)

Comment: The load will be on the deck footings, right? What does the septic tank have to do with it? I agree with Jack that this is largely a matter of preference. Maybe if you asked a more specific question....

Comment: The deck is (partially) footed on top of the septic tank, so my concern is that even though it's on the deck footings, that weight is being translated into the roof of the septic. I have no idea what the weight bearing specs of a septic tank are (or were 50 years ago)

Comment: It seems to me that how the rain barrel is being filled and the distance to the garden from the two locations should be part of the decision on its placement.

Comment: Both locations would put it just under the roof (for eavestroughs that will eventually go in) and right next to the garden, so I think in that regard they're identical

Comment: You are not doing all the extra work under the deck for the rain barrel, why is it needed under the rain barrel.  The water is currently draining on the lawn from the roof now.  Besides the footing for the structure to support the rain barrel, the pavers, etc only add minor benefits.  For me, I would put it on the lawn.  Why waste deck space on something that has no valve for deck enjoyment.

Comment: @Programmer66 I'd have to lift the rain barrel, no? Or I need to run a pump to pressurize the soaker hoses. That's the reason for the pavers etc

Comment: Yes - my comment states that a structure with footing is needed.  Pump can be attached to the support structure or on a shelves underneath.

Comment: On a different note:  If you garden exist, try the soaker hose with a garden hose to feed the soaker.  You may be disappointed in how well it waters your garden.

Comment: Figure 1/2 psi for each foot of height the top of the water is above the garden. So if the barrel is full, and 3' tall, and the deck is 3' off the ground, thats 6' water column height, so about 3psi pressure at the bottom of the pipe/hose. In reality, you will probably need to experiment with different soaker options, but the water **will** come out of anything with a hole in it...

Answer (score 1):

These answers will be opinion based so here's mine. I would rather have a 100 pound keg of beer on my deck. The rain barrel is just for the garden so I would be making it part of the garden instead of part of the recreational use of the deck. I doubt it would cause any issues if on the deck though.